# Android Studio could not resolve my own library published in jcenter

Tags: android, jcenter

I build a library and published it to jcenter.But in recent versions, this library can not be used in other projects. Once I clean the project, some error happened.

```
     > A problem occurred configuring project ':base'.
        > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':base:_debugPublishCopy'.
           > Could not resolve com.github.boybeak:adapter:2.1.5.
             Required by:
                 project :base
              > Could not resolve com.github.boybeak:adapter:2.1.5.
                 > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/boybeak/adapter/2.1.5/adapter-2.1.5.pom'.
                    > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/boybeak/adapter/2.1.5/adapter-2.1.5.pom'.
                       > Connect to localhost:50118 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused
              > Could not resolve com.github.boybeak:adapter:2.1.5.
                 > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/boybeak/nulldreams/com/github/boybeak/adapter/2.1.5/adapter-2.1.5.pom'.
                    > Could not HEAD 'http://dl.bintray.com/boybeak/nulldreams/com/github/boybeak/adapter/2.1.5/adapter-2.1.5.pom'.
                       > Connect to localhost:50118 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused
```

This error log tells me "Could not head 'https://jcenter...'", but I copy this link to Chrome. I can visit this url. 
I don't know what happened to my project. 
and the library in Jcenter[bintray:https://bintray.com/boybeak/nulldreams/adapter/2.1.5](https://bintray.com/boybeak/nulldreams/adapter/2.1.5)
This error happened int version 2.1.5. I hope someone will help me.

Comment: did you configure use proxy to Gradle or Android Studio? It tries to connect to `localhost:50118`

Comment: @DeKaNszn but other libraries such as Glide, Retrofit can be resolved. It's so Weird. Here is my gradle file link: [build.gradle](https://github.com/boybeak/DelegateAdapter/blob/master/adapter/build.gradle), it looks normal.

Comment: It can be resolved from cache, located at `~/.gradle/caches/`

Comment: @DeKaNszn Once I ping the bintray url in a command window, it shows me a "Unknown host" error. Does this matter?

Comment: @DeKaNszn Thanks for answering me. I shut down the net proxy and restart my mac, Restarting max is necessery.